# How to use powershell package manager remotely

Tags: powershell, package

I am trying to use package manager to install our packages. Those are .msi files and not Nuget Or Chocolatey Packages.

I stored them on a share drive we have.

Localy, everything run great. I run:

```
Install-package "\\nameofserver\share\program.msi"
```

However, when I try remotely like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -credential $cred -Scriptblock {Install-Package "\\nameofserver\share\program.msi"}
```

I get this error (it's in french so I'll translate):

> No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name
>   \servername\share\program.msi
>
> Use get-packagesources to find all packages sources available.

I don't have a package provider... it is a MSI file! Got any idea how to make this work?

I tried trying to include providername. Didn't work. I don't get why it works locally but NOT using `invoke-command`....

*** edit here is the code that works:

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {$null = New-PSDrive -Credential $using:Cred deploywin -Root (Split-Path -Parent $using:SharePath) -PSProvider FileSystem
        Install-Package '\servername\share\MSI\node-v11.13.0-x64.msi'}

Comment: I think you'll find a solution in the linked post; let us know if you don't. What muddied the waters in your case is that the inability to access the _UNC share_ was treated the same as a failure to find a package _online_.

Comment: Huuummm not sure it is the same problem so I don't think it is a duplicate. I already use a variable containing my credentials ($cred). I'll try the new-psdrive method but i'm not optimist.

Comment: It is not the same problem.

Comment: Providing credentials to `Invoke-Command` directly is not enough; you must use the same credentials _in the remote session_ via `$using:cred` to connect to the share _from there_.

Comment: ahhh thanks for the explanation. I'll give it a shot and report back!

Comment: Well what do you know it works! I stand humbled.